# How to display and limit the ng zorro card array to 3 and it will add pagination in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

how to limit the display of ng zorro card to per 3 card and it will add a pagination.

here's the code:
***home.component.html***

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let data of data">
    <nz-card style="width:300px;" [nzActions]="[actionSetting,actionEdit,actionEllipsis]">
        <nz-card-meta nzTitle="{{data.title}}" nzDescription="{{data.description}}" [nzAvatar]="avatarTemplate"></nz-card-meta>
    </nz-card>
    <ng-template #actionSetting>
    <div class="action-wrapper">
      <i nz-icon type="setting"></i>{{idx}}
    </div>
  </ng-template>
  <ng-template #actionEdit>
    <div class="action-wrapper">
      <i nz-icon type="edit"></i>{{idx}}
    </div>
  </ng-template>
  <ng-template #actionEllipsis>
    <div class="action-wrapper">
      <i nz-icon type="ellipsis"></i>{{idx}}
    </div>
  </ng-template>
</ng-container>
```

***home.component.ts***

```
  data = [
    { title: 'title1', description: 'description1' },
    { title: 'title2', description: 'description2' },
    { title: 'title3', description: 'description3' },
    { title: 'title4', description: 'description4' },
    { title: 'title5', description: 'description5' },
    { title: 'title6', description: 'description6' },
    { title: 'title7', description: 'description7' },
    { title: 'title8', description: 'description8' },
    { title: 'title9', description: 'description9' },
    { title: 'title10', description: 'description10' }
  ]
```

what I want to do is to limit it item to 3 card and it will add pagination.

if the array is more than 3 records it will add the pagination, if just 3 the pagination will not display.

Answer (score -1):

you should limit the ngFor iteration and then use ngIf for the pagination:

```
 <ng-contaier *ngFor="let item of data | slice:initValue:endValue">
    ....
 </ng-container>

 <div *ngIf="data.length > 3">
     <!-- pagination code  define initValue and endValue here depending on your pagination!! -->
 </div>
```

Comment: do you have an example?

Comment: How'bout, when its greater than 3. how the pagination determine the card. for example you have next button then the card should be change

Comment: I updated a bit the example, if you need some documentation https://angular.io/api/common/SlicePipe

Comment: what is the value of initValue and endvalue?